# Problema al modificar String en MVC C#

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework

la cosa es que tengo los siguientes elementos:

Este es el modelo:

```
public class Pelicula
{
    [Key]
    public int Id_Pelicula { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fecha de estreno")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Fecha_lanzamiento { get; set; }
    public int Duracion { get; set; }
    public string Nacionalidad { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Actores Principales")]
    public string PPActores { get; set; }
    public decimal Precio { get; set; }
    public string Nota { get; set; }
    public string Sinopsis { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Imagen { get; set; }
    public int GenID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GenID")]
    public virtual Genero Genero { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<Persona> Persona { get; set; }
}
```

Este es el Controlador (las líneas comentadas son algunas alternativas que probé)

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var moviess = from s in db.Pelicula
                     select s;
        ViewBag.moviess = moviess;

        var Imaagen = db.Pelicula.Select(x => x.Imagen.ToUpper().LastIndexOf("\\IMAGES")).ToList();

        //var Imaagen = db.Pelicula.Select(x => x.Imagen.ToUpper().Length - System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.Reverse(x.Imagen.ToUpper()).IndexOf("\\IMAGES"));
        //var Imaagen = db.Pelicula.Select(x => x.Imagen.ToUpper().Contains("\\IMAGES"));


        ViewBag.Imaagen = Imaagen;
        return View(db.Pelicula.ToList());
    }
```

Y esta es la vista:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCBiblio.Models.Pelicula>
@foreach (String imagen in ViewBag.Imagen)
{
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="@Url.Content(@ViewBag.Imaagen)"> <p style="text-align:center"></p></div>
}
```

Básicamente lo que quiero es que al recibir una ruta como la siguiente: `"C:\Users\dediego96\Desktop\MVCBiblio\MVCBiblio\IMAGES\aladin.png"`

se quede solo esto: `"\IMAGES\aladin.png"`

Este filtro funciona para una sola película:

```
Imaagen = Imaagen.Substring(Imaagen.ToUpper().LastIndexOf("\\IMAGES"));
```

Pero quiero que se haga para una lista. El problema que me da es que al estar usando Linq, la linea que puse en el controlador, ninguna de las 3 opciones, me deja y si lo pruebo tal y como lo enseñe me da el siguiente error:

> "'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   LastIndexOf(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.'"

Espero su ayuda, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No se si entiendo donde te esta dando el problema...esta linea te funciona? `var Imaagen = db.Pelicula.Select(x => x.Imagen.ToUpper().LastIndexOf("\\IMAGES")).ToList();`

Comment: Si exacto, por lo que he leído, es al usar el LastIndexOf con Linq, y por el error que me da es como que me esta cogiendo un int y claro, da fallo. Te hablo sin saber mucho ya que soy bastante novato en esto jeje

Comment: No te preocupes, todos fuimos novatos :) A ver si te entiendo..tu tienes por ejemplo una lista de `Pelicula`, y quieres que para todas ellas se modifique la ruta de la imagen? O que es lo que necesitas?

Comment: Si eso es, yo tengo varias películas, uno de los campos es imagen, donde se almacena la ruta de esta, y quiero que se muestren las películas de manera "dinámica", pero si pones la ruta absoluta, no aparece la foto, sin embargo, si pones la ruta /IMAGES/nbe.peli, por eso quiero pasar a la vista la ruta modificada.

Comment: `var Imaagen = db.Pelicula.Select(x => x.Imagen.ToUpper().Substring(x.Imagen.LastIndexOf("\\IMAGES"))).ToList();` algo asi te refieres?

Comment: Si pero me sigue dando el mismo error :/

Comment: Vale fallo mio, no uso Entity Framework nunca. El problema parece ser que indexof y Lastindexof no funcionan dado que no pueden "traducirse" a Sql directamente. Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46347081) a ver si usar SqlFunctions te puede servir.

Comment: Otra opcion tal vez sería crear un metodo de extension propio que devolviera el indice, aunque no se seguro si funcionaria con EF.

Comment: Voy a probar a ver que pasa, si lo consigo te marco la respuesta jeje Muchas gracias ;)

Comment: No es necesario. Si lo consigues, lo mejor es que añadas tu una respuesta y la aceptes. De todas maneras, seguramente alguien con mas experiencia en EF pueda ayudarte mejor que yo todavía.

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo solucioné de una manera tonta, simple y de casualidad:
En el contrroller..

```
var Imaagen = db.Pelicula.Select(x => x.Imagen.ToUpper()
             .Substring(x.Imagen.IndexOf("\\IMAGES"))).ToList();
```

es decir cambie el last por el index simplemente...

y en la vista lo dejé asi

```
@foreach (var imagen in ViewBag.Imaagen)
{
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="@Url.Content(@imagen)"> <p style="text-align:center"></p></div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Titulo)
```

Gracias de todas formas :)

Comment: Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto :)

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo en tu pregunta, lo que quieres es obtener una lista `List<>` de Películas con la Imagen del tipo `"\IMAGES\imagen.png"`, que luego pasarás a la Vista a través del `ViewBag`.

Para ello no haría falta que utilices Linq, puedes recorrer la lista con un `foreach` y aplicar los cambios al campo `Imagen`:

```
        List<Pelicula> Imaagen = db.Pelicula.ToList();

        foreach (var item in Imaagen)
        {
            item.Imagen = item.Imagen.Substring(item.Imagen.ToUpper().LastIndexOf("\\IMAGES"));
        }

        ViewBag.Imaagen = Imaagen;
```

Luego en la Vista, recorres el `ViewBag` con un `foreach` para mostrar la imágenes.

```
@foreach (Pelicula pelicula in (List<Pelicula>)ViewBag.Imaagen)
{
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <img src="@Url.Content(pelicula.Imagen)"> 
       <p style="text-align:center"></p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta pero ya lo saque jeje un saludo :)